# Are there any specific / difference in testing strategies and best practices that needs to be followed for SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, testing, quality-assurance

Are there any specific / difference in testing strategies and best practices that needs to be followed for SharePoint 2013 when compared to sites developed in .net/Java?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably already familiar with [.NET Framework Guidelines and Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184412(v=vs.100).aspx) which is applicable in any custom .NET application. But to SharePoint there are a number of specific issues one might not think about. The great article [How to avoid the five most common SharePoint customization mistakes](https://www.spcaf.com/blog/avoid-sharepoint-customization-mistakes/) gives great advice of what you should try to avoid, such as

1. Editing master pages without due care
2. Introducing new web parts
3. Rewriting SharePoint functionality from scratch
4. Using SharePoint Designer in a production environment
5. Being too relaxed with permissions to customize

Apart from this, there are tools to help you along the way to make development life easier and less error prone. One free tool to use is the [SharePoint Dispose Checker Tool](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Dispose-Checker-01da48e8) which checks for common errors such as not disposing web objects, or disposing them too soon. There are paid for tools available too, where the most famous one should be [SPCaf](https://www.spcaf.com/), you own SharePoint police.

As a configuration master of SharePoint I see a lot of code which fails for several reasons. The best a developer can do is to learn what SharePoint is, how it behaves and what customization you can do without code. It's often faster, and higher in quality, than trying to develop anything already present in SharePoint.

On a more general notice, one should read and learn from other developers, such as the authors of Inside SharePoint.

> ## Delivering high-quality solutions
>
> To deliver high-quality solutions it is best for the development
> environment to be as much like the production environment as possible.
> Theoretically this is true for all aspects of the environment:
> hardware, software, configuration, and data. In most cases, however,
> the hardware of a development environment cannot be the same as the
> hardware of a production environment. This is fine, as long as you are
> aware of the differences and what the impact of them might be on your
> test results.
>
> So that accurate tests can be performed in a development environment,
> the software should be the same as the software in the production
> environment. You should use the same version of Windows Server and
> SharePoint and a similar version of SQL Server. If the production
> environment has SharePoint Server installed, make sure the development
> environment doesn’t have SharePoint Foundation installed. If the
> production server has a Windows service pack installed on it, make
> sure you install the same service pack in the development environment.
>
> . . .
>
> In order to get accurate test results, it is also very helpful to have
> representative sample data and test users. The data will help you
> perform the same type of actions that a user would. If you are able to
> load enough sample data into your development environment, it will
> also help you test the scalability of your solution, at least to a
> certain extent. Most custom solutions perform very well with only a
> couple of documents, users, or sites, but when there are tens of
> thousands it might be a completely different story. Even if you can’t
> test on the scale of your production environment, you should always
> keep in mind what numbers your solution will have to cope with after
> it’s in production. It is always a good idea to at least make sure
> that you test whether your application will keep working past the list
> view threshold. The list view threshold is a web application setting
> that can be adjusted in Central Administration that tells SharePoint
> how many items can be requested from the database in a single query.
> The default list view threshold is 5,000.

From [SharePoint Development Practices and Techniques](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2222445)

Comment: @Scorpio Great! If this answer helped you, you can mark this answer accepted, and it may help others in the future with the same question. Thank you :-)